# Python comparison of previous data

Tags: python, compare

I have a program that asks the user for raw input and then displays it. What I want to do is this:

If the user enters data that was different from the previous data     entered, then update the data, else do nothing.

So all I'm doing is checking whether the data the user enters is the same as the one they entered before but I would like to know how I go about doing this in Python.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are here to help you when you have a problem. But not to do your assignments for you

Comment: Thank you for the response, more specifically I have a prompt asking the user the enter data for an array like so : raw_input('Enter data1, data2, data3:') I just have no clue how it works in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural way to do this is with a data structure that guarantees that its elements are unique. For instance, try defining a set and adding any new user input to it. If you try to add a string that's already in the set, it will do nothing.

```
record = set()
while True:  # just an example; you'll need to end the loop somehow
    message = raw_input('give me data! ')
    record.add(message)
print record
```

Comment: This seems to be a more compact way of doing this, thanks I really wasn't sure what to do with to compare the two!

Comment: @zetadon you can write this as: `record = set(iter(lambda: raw_input('give me data!'), ''))` if you really wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
user_input = raw_input('enter an input\n')
user_input2 = raw_input('confirm your input\n')
if user_input != user_input2:
    print 'updating...'
    user_input = user_input2
print 'Input is: {}'.format(user_input)
```

If you need to split up a string of input, see the documentation for str.split and other handy built in functions: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split